# Setting classpath for org.jruby.Main?

Tags: java, ruby, rubygems, classpath, jruby

I'm running JRuby as such:

```
Main jrubyRunner = new Main()
jrubyRunner.main(sassCompileCommandLineArgs)
```

I have some gems I've compiled into jars. How do I include those jars on the classpath that `jrubyRunner` will use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static def setupCompassInvocationArgs =
['-e', "require 'rubygems';gem 'compass'; load Gem.bin_path('compass', 'compass')"]

protected def runCompassCommand(def compassArgs) {
    Main main = new Main()
    main.run([setupCompassInvocationArgs, compassArgs].flatten() as String[])
}
```

The first bit is what you need to load various gems.